# How do I set flutter app timeline according to device time?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

For example, I want to execute some function after 2 hours from the current time on the device (I did this using Timer()). But I want if I change the time on the device faster than 2 hours, those functions will execute immediately instead of waiting 2 hours.
Please tell me the solution.
Thank you !

Comment: You can change the time on the setting screen. However, if there is a problem with the lifecycle of the app, the desired behavior will not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shared preferences package

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

When you wish to start the timer get the datetime and save it in shared preferences

```dart
SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
_prefs.setString('startTime', DateTime.now().toString());
```

Now to check the difference

```dart
DateTime startTime = DateTime.parse(_prefs.getString('startTime'));
if(startTime.add(Duration(hours:2)).isBefore(DateTime.now())
{
  print("2 hours are over");
}
```

If you wish to check it every second add the checker in a periodic timer of duration 1 second